# creating archive using tar including all 'dotfiles' but excluding all subdirectories and /wo directory structure

Tags: tar

I want to backup all the 'dotfiles' (f.e. `.zshrc`) under my home directory with **tar**, but excluding the directory structure and all subdirectories.

I've tried it several times with different commands, but the best i achieved was an archive which included the hidden directories under `$HOME` as well.

```
#!/bin/zsh
BACKUPFILE=dotfile_backup.tar.gz
tar --create --file=$HOME/$BACKUPFILE --auto-compress --no-recursion --exclude=. --exclude=.. --exclude=*/ --directory=$HOME .*
```

I also thought about using `find` and piping the result to tar, but with no luck. Does somebody know how to achieve this - seemingly easy - task?

PS: Most of the time when I'm using tar to create an archive, i have to think about xkcd comic:

[image: xkcd 1168] :)

Comment: The answer of *sim* works, but if someone got a regex that matches only the hidden files, please post it!

Comment: Surely this would be better achieved with your shell. I understand that zsh has globs that select only files -- `*(.)` -- and I think it excludes `.` and `..` from `.*` by default (and they wouldn't be picked up by `.*(.)` anyway, since it selects only files). I don't use zsh myself, so I'm not sure enough to turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this command to backup all your dotfiles (`.<something>`) in your `$HOME` directory:

```
$ cd ~
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ".*" -exec tar zcvf dotfiles.tar.gz {} +
```

### regex using just tar?

#### method #1

I researched this quite a bit and came up empty. The limiting factor would be that when `tar` is performing it's excludes, the trailing slash (`/`) that shows up with directories is not part of the equation when tar is performing its pattern match.

Here's an example:

```
$ tar -v --create --file=do.tar.gz --auto-compress --no-recursion --exclude={'.','..','.*/'} .*
.qalculate/
.qt/
.qterm/
.qtoctave/
.RapidSVN
.RData
.Rhistory
```

This variant includes an exclude of `.*/` and you can see with the verbose switch turned on to tar, `-v`, that these directories are passing through that exclude.

#### method #2

I thought maybe the switches `--no-wildcards-match-slash` or `--wildcards-match-slash` would relax the greediness of the `.*/` but this had no effect either.

Taking the slash out of the exclude, `.*` wasn't an option either since that would tell `tar` to exclude all the dotfiles and dotdirectories:

```
$ tar -v --create --file=do.tar.gz --auto-compress --no-recursion --exclude={'.','..','.*'} .*
$
```

#### method #3 (Ugly!)

So the only other alternative I can conceive is to provide a list of files to `tar`. Something like this:

```
$ tar -v --create --file=do.tar.gz --auto-compress --no-recursion --wildcards-match-slash --exclude={'.','..','.*/'} $(ls -aF | grep -E "^\..*[^/]$")
.RapidSVN
.RData
.Rhistory
```

This approach has issues if the number of files exceeds the maximum amount of space for passing arguments to a command would be one glaring issue. The other is that it's ugly and overly complex.

#### so what did we learn?

There doesn't appear to be a straight-forward and elegant way to acomplish this using `tar` & regular expressions. So as to @terdon's comment, `find ... | tar ...` is really the more appropriate way to do this.

Comment: I really wanted to get it done with `regex`, but i should have known that it won't work that way :)

Comment: @klingt.net - it should be possible, I'm looking now.

Comment: @klingt.net why would you prefer the more complicated way? Using `regex` you will probably need to escape the leading dot and will have trouble ignoring `.` and `..`. I am sure it is possible as slm will probably demonstrate but I don't see why it would be worthwhile.

Comment: @sim: i've got another question, what does the {} and the + at the end of the line do?

Comment: @terdon i know, but i want to see where the problem of my regex was.

Comment: @klingt.net - everything that the `find` command finds get's passed as an argument to `tar`. The `{}` says where you want those results to go in the corresponding `-exec` command. The `+` says to add as many results from `find` as will fit on the command line and call `tar` only a couple of times rather than every time a result is found.

Comment: @klingt.net - there isn't a way to accomplish this using `regex` and `tar` because there is no way to isolate the dot directories (`.blah/`). Tar doesn't use the trailing slash when doing the exclude.

Comment: @klingt.net - I've expanded the answer to show the limits of the regex approach.

Comment: Your find command is going to fail is the amount of files gets too large (because the max command length), and it only tars the files from the last invocation

Comment: @Ferrybig that's correct

Answer (score 4):

This kind of control over matching files is way outside tar's comfort zone. Its rules for matching files are limited to simple matches over names.

`find` is one way, but since you have zsh, you have it easier:

```
tar -cf "$HOME/$BACKUPFILE" --auto-compress .*(.)
```

That `.` in parentheses at the end of the wildcard expression is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) that says “only match regular files”.

Symbolic links to regular files are not matched. If you change to `.*(-.)`, they will be included, but the file won't end up in the archive unless it's also included. If you want to replace symbolic link by their targets, make that `.*(-.:A)` — `:A` adds the [history expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) that resolves all symbolic links to a path that doesn't use symbolic links.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on slm's, but I will also show you how to include directories beginning with `.`

To zip up dot files in your home directory:

```
$ cd
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ".?*" -exec tar czfv dotfiles.tgz {} +
```

To include directories:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name ".?*" -exec tar czfv dotfiles.tgz {} +
```

The `?` is optional in the first command, but not in the second, otherwise, `find` will include the `.` (current) directory.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
tar -C $HOME -cvzf dotfiles.tgz .
```